# Caching larger flv files 5mb +

Tags: .htaccess, flv

I'm using flowplayer, and told .htaccess to cache flv files for 30 minutes. When the files are under 5mb it caches, if over that, it doesn't. How do I force cache like youtube does?

5mb from what I've found out is a browser default. If youtube is able to bypass that, I should be able to as well. Any ideas?

Comment: What makes you so sure YouTube is caching more than 5 Mb locally?

Comment: I view HD video files of 1080p, and reload the page I viewed them on and it loads the full video preloaded. To correct myself, I've found that my site caches up to 40mb instead of 5. Still need it to cache larger files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you could bypass browser limits, doing so would be bad net citizenship.  Basically, that would be setting out to use more of the user's resources than the user has authorized.  Don't do it.

I don't think YouTube is locally caching more than your browser is allowing.  I view a large HD video file and reload the page and the video is not preloaded.  I don't see what you say you're seeing in the comment on your question.

Of coures, that behavior may be browser-dependent.  [This post](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/04/26/call-to-improve-browser-caching/) shows cache sizes for different browsers as of last year and they are certainly as large or larger now.

Comment: I was using Safari and Chrome when testing, explains why HD videos stayed loaded on my Mac. These two browsers take in the most info. Thank you very much for this.